# Desktop vs Mobile Chrome rendering differently ::after content

Tags: html, css, sass

With the same HTML/CSS3 markup, desktop is rendering the after-pseudo element properly in the middle of the container, whereas the mobile Android 7.0 Chrome (same version 69.0.xxx) renders the element aligned differently (=wrong). Any ideas how to get them rendered in same way without resorting to hacks?

I now have userAgent hack to check the "Android" string and with added extra class that changes the x-mark top position a bit. Font is "-apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica" in both cases. Head-tag has `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

Code:

```css
.input-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.clear-button {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}

.clear-button:after {
        position: absolute;
        content: "\02DF";
        font-size: 80px;
        line-height: 80px;
        height: 53.33333px;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
    }
```

```html
<div class="input-container">
  <div class="clear-button"></div>
</div>
```

Desktop image:
[desktop_render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCTjG.png)

Mobile image:
[mobile_android_render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWNF1.png)

Comment: I have found the same issue when trying to create CSS based icons. Very irritating.